# Additional non-negativity constraints in nleqslv

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve a system of non-linear equations

```
x1 = f(x1, x2)
x2 = g(x1, x2)
```

subject to `x1 >= 0`, `x2 >= 0`

Using nleqslv, I set up the return vector of my function to be optimized as follows:

```
y[1] = x[1] - f(x[1], x[2])
y[2] = x[2] - g(x[1], x[2])
y[3] = -x[1]
y[4] = -x[2]
```

where the last two should reflect the non-negativy constraints.

Calling *nleqslv* yields:

"Jacobian is singular (1/condition=0.0e+000) (see allowSingular option)"

and calling with allowSingular = T yields:

"x-values within tolerance 'xtol'"

which makes sense, since y[4] doesn't change as x[4] is changed (by construction, doesn't respond to it at all).

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You can try a transformation for your `x[..]`. Call the arguments `z` instead of `x`.  And then use `x <- exp(z)` which will force `x>0`. You could also try `x <- z^2` i.e. using squaring. However this may make your problem ill conditioned. You will have to experiment. If you want more help you will need to provide the actual definition of your functions `f` and `g`.

Comment: So if I transform like that, I have to use `sqrt(x)` throughout, right? Didn't help much. `f(x1,x2) = .9- x2`  and `g(x1,x2) = 2 - sqrt(x1+x2)`. For this simply case I could of course solve it manually, but I eventually want to extend it to a system of `N` equations.

Comment: No. Exactly the other way around. Your functions have arguments `z[1]` and `z[2]` and you set `x <- z^2`. And then `x[1]` is positive. If you wish you could use `x <- x^2` directly but I feel that that obscures the transformation.

Comment: Yes, I set `x = z^2` in the beginning. But in order to preserve correct assignment of `y[1]` and `y[2]` I have to use `y[1]=sqrt(x[1]) - f(sqrt(x[1]), sqrt[x[2]])`, no?

Comment: No. Just use your result for `x`.

Comment: No, no, no. Use `x`. Don't take the square root.

Comment: In cases like this I use a nonlinear programming solver that allows bounds on variables. Either use a dummy objective or minimize sum of squared errors if feasibility is difficult to attain.

Comment: Which nonlinear programming solver allows for bounds on variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
f <- function(z) {
    x <- z^2  # this will force x to be >= 0; other tranformations are   possible
    y <- numeric(2)
    y[1] <- x[1] - f(x[1], x[2])
    y[2] <- x[2] - g(x[1], x[2])
    y
}
```

and then use `nleqslv` to solve function `f` with appropriate starting values for the transformed variables.
So if your starting values are now in `xstart` use

```
zstart <- sqrt(xstart)
```

for the transformed problem.
And to get the result of solving in the correct units just use `^2` on the result given by `nleqslv`.

Comment: Now I understand! This works fine for two-dimensional vector now, but once I add a third one, `nleqslv` stops with "No better point found (algorithm has stalled)".

Comment: Experiment with different starting values. Use `testnslv` in the package to see if methods other than the default can find a solution. It is quite possible.